# AMD Kernel Modesetting

Tags: drivers

I am using AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT graphics card which mostly results in screene freezing at boot up and works rarely. Below is the report generated the one time it worked. I am new to Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) and trying to figure out how to set the kernel modesettig default to my AMDGPU driver. Could someone please advise? Thanks.

Report below:

```
~$ dmesg | grep -i amdgpu
[    5.615255] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    5.615380] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 0: 0x40000000 -> 0x4fffffff
[    5.615381] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 2: 0x50000000 -> 0x501fffff
[    5.615382] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 5: 0x50300000 -> 0x5037ffff
[    5.615383] fb0: switching to amdgpudrmfb from EFI VGA
[    5.615445] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    5.615469] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    5.652109] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: VRAM: 8176M 0x0000008000000000 - 0x00000081FEFFFFFF (8176M used)
[    5.652110] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: GART: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF
[    5.652201] [drm] amdgpu: 8176M of VRAM memory ready
[    5.652202] [drm] amdgpu: 8176M of GTT memory ready.
[    6.495517] amdgpu: [powerplay] smu driver if version = 0x00000034, smu fw if version = 0x00000036, smu fw version = 0x00351a00 (53.26.0)
[    6.495518] amdgpu: [powerplay] SMU driver if version not matched
[    6.499547] amdgpu: [powerplay] SMU is initialized successfully!
[    6.524533] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: bound 0000:07:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[    6.569440] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    6.626530] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    6.667364] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 0(gfx_0.0.0) uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[    6.667365] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 1(gfx_0.1.0) uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[    6.667366] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 2(comp_1.0.0) uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[    6.667367] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 3(comp_1.1.0) uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[    6.667367] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 4(comp_1.2.0) uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[    6.667368] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 5(comp_1.3.0) uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[    6.667368] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 6(comp_1.0.1) uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[    6.667369] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 7(comp_1.1.1) uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[    6.667369] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 8(comp_1.2.1) uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[    6.667370] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 9(comp_1.3.1) uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[    6.667371] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 10(kiq_2.1.0) uses VM inv eng 14 on hub 0
[    6.667371] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 11(sdma0) uses VM inv eng 15 on hub 0
[    6.667372] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 12(sdma1) uses VM inv eng 16 on hub 0
[    6.667373] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 13(vcn_dec) uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[    6.667373] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 14(vcn_enc0) uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[    6.667374] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 15(vcn_enc1) uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[    6.667374] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 16(vcn_jpeg) uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 1
[    6.667491] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.35.0 20150101 for 0000:07:00.0 on minor 0
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the log.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, the computer rarely boots with my GPU and when it does, I get the above report on the graphics driver. I have a suspicion that amdgpu modesetting kernel is not enabled by default and the screen freezes. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think that "modsetting is not enabled". It may be a hardware issue, or the adapter is poorly supported by kernel, or some hardware incompatibility.